# mount point-permission denied !

Tags: linux, mount

I created a fuse mountpoint. After mounting, the file permissions are all screwed up and it says I cannot ls or cd. Permission denied.

The file permissions look like this: d????????? ? ? ? ? ? temp

and when i list the mounted devices I get: /dev/fuse on /temp type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev)

I used mono-fuse. I just created a new folder with permissions 777 and then did a mount. After unmounting I can do all operations, but when I mount, I get such error.

I used HelloFS.exe that comes along with mono fuse for testing. Can someone shed some light on this weird behavior and what mistake ive done. Thank you !!

-Sethu

Comment: Some more information would be helpful, what are the exact commands you entered?

Comment: I have a C# program that will mount azure storage on the mount point. Once I run this code, the permissions gets screwed up like this. I cannot do an ls or cd to that mountpoint.

Comment: Can you include the C# program in the question, or is it private?

Comment: Hi,
The issue got solved. I was using mono fuse. mono fuse has properties AllowAccessToRoot and AllowAccessToOthers. Both were set to false. Thus I enabled these 2 bool variables and set allow others flag in /etc/fuse.conf . Now It works !! Thanks Josh !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that you're trying to access another user's fusermount (or `sudo`ing your own) and, because fuse is (usually) single-user, you're having issues.

Either:

- Make sure that you own the fusermount
- Use the `allow_other` or `allow_root` option (or alternative)

Comment: Hey Josh, Im a newbie, can you please tell me where to use these options? in /etc/fstab ?? Thanks !

Comment: @sethu: It could be something like `fusermount -o allow_root mountpoint` but it depends on what you're trying to do and how you're trying to do it.

Comment: Hi,
The issue got solved. I was using mono fuse. mono fuse has properties AllowAccessToRoot and AllowAccessToOthers. Both were set to false. Thus I enabled these 2 bool variables and set allow others flag in /etc/fuse.conf . Now It works !! Thanks Josh !!

Comment: @sethu: Could you click the tick next to my name to mark it as the solution? That way people can see at a glance that the question is already solved, and I get some points :P

Comment: @Josh, oh i never knew that, and what is that 0,-1 and other stuff??

Comment: @sethu: Users can vote on how clear a question is, or how good an answer is, the vote count is then displayed next to the question and the poster is awarded reputation. More about reputation here: http://superuser.com/faq#reputation